# What's the point of modular arithmetics ?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, modules

In my math 123 class were learning about cryptography and in the 3rd section of cryptography we are learning about modules and modular arithmetic's the book does a poor job of explaining it and also how it relates to cryptography. There's also a table involved that has something to do with a one way function.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good
question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: The idea is that in modular arithmetic, exponentiation is easy to compute, but the inverse (logarithm) is going to be hard. Exponentiation is going to be the one-way function that encryption algorithm will exploit.